# Modal Form se cierra en submit vacío

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Tengo un modal con un form de bootstrap para login. Lo probé sin el modal y las valdaciones de usuario/contraseña funcionan correctamente.
En modal también funciona cuando capturo usuario y contraseña validos, si me redirige. **Pero** si dejo campos vacíos ó inválidos, al dar clic en el submit, el modal se cierra. Y hasta que vuelvo a abrir el modal me muestra los errores que tuve "usuario no encontrado ó escribe tu usuario etc". No he encontrado la manera de que no se cierre al dar submit.
**Las validaciones si las hace pero las veo hasta que vuelvo a abrir el MODAL,
Como en esta imagen:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
      id="idModal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"> <!--evita el cierre con telcado o mouse-->
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       
                       <span class="sr-only">cerrar</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                   TITULO
                </h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal cuerpo -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
       <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"   value="<?php echo $username; ?>" >
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
           
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                   </form>
            </div>
                       <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">   Close
                </button>
                   <a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php"> Regresar</a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Igual dejo el codigo PHP

```
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Captura tu usuario.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Captura tu contraseña.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: Departamentos/view.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "pass incorecto.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "no se encontro cuenta.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "ocurrio un errror.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Porque no usan Ajax para enviar el formulario?

Comment: Que tal José, entiendo, sin embargo aun no entro a esa parte de Ajax. Intento aprender mediante PHP unicamente.

Comment: Me uno a la sugerencia de @JoséVásquez, porque precisamente esa es una de las principales ventajas de usar modales, actualizar solo un contenedor en lugar de recargar toda la página.

Comment: @Triby x2, Jose Tapia, solo cambiarias el `form` por `ajax` para que la solicitud se procese en segundo plano(sin tener que recargar la pagina) y hacer lo que quieres (validar sin que se cierre el modal)

Comment: Ponle un Id a tu formulario e intenta lo siguiente: `$( "#modalFormLogin" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: Para usar AJAX, se realiza alguna sustitución de código? o Solo es añadir esa parte. Me refiero si Ajax es "en lugar de?"
Ya no utilizaría todo el codigo PHP que tengo ahí?

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues que es y para que sirve. Ya que solo es un tecnica para hacer peticiones en segundo plano, a parte de esto tambien existe `fetch`. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, lo que se haria es capturar el evento `submit` para enviarlo despues por ajax, como lo pone @OscarLudick

Comment: Porque le colocan tantas vueltas, intentaste con colocar un required en los input username y password?

Comment: @ernestojimenez, el `required` soluciona el problema de campos vacíos, pero no lo de mostrar errores por que usuario no existe o contraseña incorrecta.